# Quitting a Sticky Keys sequence?

Tags: keyboard, gnome3, accessibility

When Sticky Keys is enabled, how do you quit a key sequence after pressing a modifier by accident?

https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en suggested <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to reset, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel a Sticky Keys sequence, which did not work.

EDIT:

Pressing a modifier *twice* does not disable it.

Environment is Gnome Shell 3.22.3.

I am enabling Sticky Keys via the Universal Access applet.

Comment: Please describe your exact scenario. For instance, if I typed Shift, and then changed my mind, pressing Shift _twice_ again works for me (once to make it on for more than one key, and once again to disable it). Just like it does on a phone.

Comment: @mosvy Added environment to description.

Comment: What key sequence, precisely? (I have gnome 3.30.2 here, so a bit more recent than yours)

Comment: @mosvy Any key sequence that I have tried. Pressing either Shift or Control or Alt twice does not disable them.

Comment: I have the same problem. Once Sticky Keys is activated, pressing a modifier once makes it ready to modify the next key. Pressing it twice makes it *locked* in the sense that it won't be released at the next non-modifier-key press. Finally pressing it three times releases it.

If one presses another modifier after another one has been activated, the two will be active simultaneously. 

This leads to really confusing situations if one doesn't keep the press count mentally...

Comment: https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/6852#issuecomment-1352547670 check this